# Convert Apple Cocoa Core Data timestamp in Excel

Tags: cocoa, excel-formula, epoch

I'm trying to convert the Cocoa timestamps to human-readable dates with time.  For context, these numbers are coming from the history.db file within ~/Library/ for Safari.  I can convert individual numbers with the awesome tool at epochconverter.com, but they do not offer a batch converter for Cocoa.

As an example, 638490901.575263 should convert to Friday, March 26, 2021 3:35:01 PM GMT-07:00.  In Excel, I'm using:

=("cell reference"/86400000) + DATE(2001,1,1), but getting 1/8/01 9:21 AM.  Looks like I need to add time for the Cocoa Epoch delta, but unsure how to do that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `0` in the formula, the number is the number of seconds since the start of 1/1/2001.  There are `86400` seconds in a day.  Then add the start date so we get the correct number of dates from 12/31/1899 which is what Excel uses.  Then we need to subtract 7 hours to get the correct time zone difference.

```
=(A1/86400) + DATE(2001,1,1) - TIME(7,0,0)
```

[image]